# Issue inserting Recordtype for object

Tags: api, rest, record-type, java

I am writing a JAVA-application that mainly functions as a CRUD-platform for my employees. On this application, users can manage data from a specific objects. I am using REST-API.

Now, here is my method for inserting values:

```
  public void createTimeTracking(String subject, String date) {
    System.out.println("\n_______________ Time-Tracking INSERT _______________");

    String uri = baseUri + "/sobjects/Time_Tracking__c/";
    try {

        //create the JSON object containing the new lead details.
        JSONObject tt = new JSONObject();

        tt.put("TimeTrackingRecordTypeId", chosenProject.getProjectRecordTypeId());
        tt.put("Subject__c", subject);
        tt.put("Project__c", getChosenProject().getProjectId());
        tt.put("Work_Package__c", getChosenWorkPackage().getWorkPackageId());
        tt.put("Date__c", date);
        tt.put("Internal_Contact__c", benutzer.getInternalContactId());
        tt.put("Status__c", "Submitted by Employee");

        System.out.println("JSON for car record to be inserted:\n" + tt.toString(1));

        //Construct the objects needed for the request
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.addHeader(oauthHeader);
        httpPost.addHeader(prettyPrintHeader);
        // The message we are going to post
        StringEntity body = new StringEntity(tt.toString(1));
        body.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(body);


        //Make the request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        //Process the results
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response_string);

        if (statusCode == 201) {
            // Store the retrieved lead id to use when we update the lead.
            String ttId = json.getString("id");
            System.out.println("New TT id from response: " + ttId);
        } else {

            System.out.println("Insertion unsuccessful. Status code returned is " + statusCode);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Issue creating JSON or processing results");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Issue creating JSON or processing results
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Now, I can exclude that any other record but "RecordTypeId" is causing this issue, because I can insert the rest of the values without any JSON-Exception.

The RecordTypeId is valid, but apparently it's not, when it keeps failing to proceed the request..

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: `RecordTypeId` field will be available if  recordType is enabled for that sobject.

Answer (score 0):

The RecordType field should be called `RecordTypeId` not `TimeTrackingRecordTypeId`. This usage of an invalid field name is causing the API to return an error response, error response are arrays in json, not a json object, so your attempt to always decode the response as a json object fails in this case. You need to check the status code to see if its 2xx before trying to decode the response as a json object, or if the status code is >= 300 decode the response as a json array instead.